# Add button to map in ios application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, mapkit

I'm currently working on an app that utilizes maps. One feature I'd like to implant is to have a full screen map with a button/handle on the side that would allow a user navigate between screens. See the example from runkeeper below:
[image]

Would anyone have any insight/idea where to begin with this? I'm even having a tough time finding appropriate google keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your button to your view after adding mapView(over your map view).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an new iOS project. In the info.plist set UIStatusBarHidden to YES.
In your map view add

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

In the method that handle the button event add:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
     NewViewcontroller *newViewC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushNavigationController: newViewC animated: YES];
     [newViewC release];
}
```